# Singleton class in Java, make member variable thread safe without using synchronization block

Tags: java

I have a Singleton class and a private member variable counter. I have a public getCounter() method which increments the counter by 1 and returns it. I am using this Singleton class in a web application, so I want to make this variable and method thread safe. But I don't want to use synchronization methods or blocks. Do we have any other oops way to achieve this concurrency in my Singleton class ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) (and other [atomic primitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html)), it has method [incrementAndGet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet()). I guess it's ideal for you.

Example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class Singleton { 
    // singleton logic ommited
    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Comment: you could enhance your answer with an example and you could link the class and method to the corresponding javadoc.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Is there any other oops concepts that we can use in the combination to achieve this concurrency?